# Sorting an Existing Map by Value in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to sort a Map by value using Scala but no luck any help will be appreciable.
"null value can be any order"

Input:

```
Map(dkd-> 2, dtes-> 3,test-> 4, dstl-> null,tsst-> null, tetd-> null ,est1-> 1)
```

Output

```
Map(est1-> 1, dkd-> 2, dtes-> 3, test-> 4, tsst-> null, dstl-> null, tetd-> null)
```

or

```
Map(est1-> 1, dkd-> 2, dtes-> 3, test-> 4, dstl-> null, tetd-> null, tsst-> null)
```

or

`Map(est1-> 1, dkd-> 2, dtes-> 3, test-> 4, tetd-> null, dstl-> null, tsst-> null`)

Comment: Maps are not sorted, especially not by value. Why do you care about the order? Is for printing?

Comment: If you need to sort a map, you are using the wrong structure, because maps are not meant to be accessed by order, they are supposed to be accessed by key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Map`, by definition, has no order, but a `List` does.

```
Map("dkd"-> 2
  , "dstl"-> null
  , "test"-> 4
  , "tsst"-> null
  , "dtes"-> 3
  , "tetd"-> null
  , "est1"-> 1
  ).toList.sortBy{
    case (_:String,i:Int) => i
    case _ => Int.MaxValue
  }
//res0: List[(String, Any)] = 
// List((est1,1)
//    , (dkd,2)
//    , (dtes,3)
//    , (test,4)
//    , (tsst,null)
//    , (dstl,null)
//    , (tetd,null))
```